# How can I insert dash in every 2 even number in javascript

Tags: javascript

So I'm trying to create a code that will insert dash in every even numbers it encountered (based on the users input)

I tried this

```js
var num = window.prompt();
var str = num.toString();
var result = [str[0]];
for (var x = 1; x < str.length; x++) {
  if (str[x - 1] % 2 === 0 && str[x] % 2 === 0) {
    result.push('-', str[x]);
  } else {
    result.push(str[x]);
  }
}
console.log(result.join(''));
```

I expect that it will give result but it doesnt

Comment: Can you give a concrete example of an input and the expected output?

Comment: what are you getting right now?

Comment: @CertainPerformance For example if you accept 025468 the output should be 0-254-6-8

Comment: @DavidThomas typo

Comment: @A.A. Basically nothing after the prompt

Comment: your code it totally working

Comment: @OmriAttiya what do you think is the problem why it is not working on mine?

Comment: @EliseoBuenaSanMiguel I edited your question to a snippet and it worked

Comment: @OmriAttiya is it just me or its only producing a 12345 when I enter 12345

Comment: @EliseoBuenaSanMiguel your code is working, i tested it too, but check out the answer given below, its a way better and more efficent way to solve this problem with a couple of lines.

Answer (score 2):

Using regexp with lookahead:

```js
let str = '025468';
let dashedStr = str.replace(/[02468](?=[02468])/g, '$&-');
console.log(dashedStr);
```

EDIT: I do not know what could be confusing in

> `let str = prompt("Enter a number");` instead of the first line

but here you go.

```js
let str = prompt("Enter a number");
let dashedStr = str.replace(/[02468](?=[02468])/g, '$&-');
console.log(dashedStr);
```

Comment: ^ saves a lot of time and is quick and secure

Comment: You already know how to do it: `let str = prompt("Enter a number");` instead of the first line.

Comment: Sir I know its a bother but can you give the whole code of it.. Im a little bit confused.. pardon

Answer (score -1):

I wrote a small function for it, here is the whole code for it. Splice is better that push since it is used for changing the contents of an array whereas push is used to add an element to the end of an array

```
var str = ['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', 'w', 'o', 'r', 'l', 'd']
var wordDash = str => {
    for (let index = 0; index < str.length; index++) {
        if (index % 2 == 0) {
            str.splice([index + 1], 0, '-')
        }
    }
    console.log(str)
}

wordDash(str)
```